# Can not find protocol Decleration

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

First ViewController Controller . h File

```
@protocol MyClassNameDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)getClassName:(NSString *)strClassName;
@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<MyClassNameDelegate>
{
    id <MyClassNameDelegate>delegate;

}

@property (nonatomic,strong)id<MyClassNameDelegate>delegate;
```

First ViewController Controller . M File

```
-(void)getClassName:(NSString *)strClassName
{
    self.txtClass.text=strClassName;
}
```

Call this method from another View Controller

so i declare the protocol in seconView Controller .h File like below code

```
@interface ClassViewController : UIViewController <MyClassNameDelegate>  // Adopt protocol here
{
    NSArray * arryClass;

}
```

SecondView . M file

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellText = cell.textLabel.text;

    ViewController * objViewController = [[ViewController alloc]init];

    objViewController.delegate=self;

    [objViewController.delegate getClassName:cellText];  // Call delegate method from here 


    NSLog(@"%@",cellText);
}
```

Can not find protocol Declaration error occurred. what is wrong with this code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `#import FirstViewController.h`?

Comment: imported that file in second View controller

Comment: YEs, but I gues you imported it in the .m. Because of the declaration in the .h file, you must import the FirstViewController.h in the .h of ClassViewController.

Comment: I have done the same but still not working

Comment: have you using storyboards in your app?

Comment: do you get any warning with this "objViewController.delegate=self;" line, in table view cell implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you import ViewController.h in the ClassViewController.m file? That triggers exactly that error message...

Comment: This isn't an answer it is a question to gather more information so its a comment

Comment: Now you're being pedantic Popeye. It's an answer phrased as a question, with an explanation following.

Answer (score 0):

change the line `[objViewController.delegate getClassName:cellText];` to `[objViewController getClassName:cellText];` it works fine.

Comment: ViewController * objViewController   =  [[ViewController alloc]init];   instead of  above line you can use   ViewController * objViewController =  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"]; because u are using storyboard

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (nonatomic,strong)id<MyClassNameDelegate>delegate;
```

Change to

```
@property (nonatomic,weak)id <MyClassNameDelegate> delegateCustom;
```

and use delegateCustom everywhere. Maybe its getting confused with custom delegate and tableview delegate.